# How to add Floating(decimal) hour in DateTime's DATEADD function?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to add some hours in SQL SERVER using DATEADD function. But when I try this,

```
SELECT DATEADD(Hour, 0.5, GETDATE())
```

It is not adding 0.5 hour. How to solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't. It's well describer on documentation: [DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

> ***number***
>
> Is an expression that can be resolved to an int that is added
>   to a datepart of date. User-defined variables are valid.
>
> **If you specify a value with a decimal fraction, the fraction is truncated and
>   not rounded.**

***UPDATE***

You could try that:

```
SELECT DATEADD(Second, 0.5 * 60 * 60, GETDATE())
```

Of course - you can change `DATEPART` and multiplier to get desired precision.

Comment: @marc_s, Thanks. The value is dynamic and is coming from another database table which can be int or float.

Comment: @user960567 Write your own function which will internally call `DATEADD` proper number of times - one for days, one for hours, minutes, etc.

Comment: @user960567: well, the documentation seems ***pretty clear*** - it will ***not work*** with `DATEADD(HOURS, 0.5)` - you'll have to adapt your code to the reality.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, Can you please show an example? I will glad for you?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, Thanks I think this will work for all my cases. But still it lacks the beauty of Addhours http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can't add parts of hours, just full hours. Use `minute` for half an hour

```
SELECT DATEADD(minute, 30, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I can't fixed this. I just have to add hours may in int format or float. Thinkning similar what the .NET DateTime.AddHours works

Answer (score 0):

I have found another approach to this where adding a number to the date instead of using the function works for fractions.  For example:

```
GETDATE() + n
```

where **n is the number of days**.  For 1 half hour, you can use:

```
GETDATE() + 0.5/24
```